# Alamofire singleton webservercall class error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, swift2

Im working on a project in `swift 3.0` along with the support of `Alamofire` framework as to interline my webservercalls. Basically I wants to use a singleton class that I previously used in `swift 2.3` where I declare the method, and then in whatever the viewcontroller I wants to execute it I call the method as bellow.

```
APIManager.sharedInstance.login(username, password: password, completion: { (user,success) in

                if success {

                }

                }) { (error) in       

 }
```

My requirement is to get this code work in `swift 3.0` so I could carry on the work. Help on this would much appreciate. The code of My singleton  class as bellow (this code is in `swift 2.3`, I want this in 3.0).

```
    import UIKit
    import Alamofire
    import SwiftyJSON

struct Singleton {
  static let instance : APIManager = APIManager()
}

public class APIManager: NSObject {
  public class var sharedInstance: APIManager {
    return Singleton.instance
  }

  let manager = Manager()

  override init() {

  }

  //MARK:====Login====

  //MARK: methods

  func login(username: String, password: String, completion: (user: User, success: Bool) -> (), failed:(error: NSError) -> ()) -> Request {
    let urlRequest // Create a URLRequest and pass to the method

    return manager.request(urlRequest)
      .validate()
      .responseJSON { response in
        if let error = response.result.error {
          failed(error: error)
          print(error)
          return;
        }
        let ok = ((response.result.value as! JSONDictionary)["success"] as? Bool)!
        let userJson = JSON((response.result.value as! JSONDictionary)["user"]!)

        let token = ((response.result.value as! JSONDictionary)["token"] as? String)!
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(token, forKey: UserDefaultKey.Token)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        let user = User(json: userJson)
        completion(user: user,success: ok)

        print ("Auth is :  \(token)")


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: SO WHERE THE PROBLEM  PUT SOME DETAILS HERE

Comment: Sir as I have mentioned in my body obviously my requirement is to convert this code in to swift 3.0 since its written in swift 2.3. Your help would much appreciate

Comment: I THINK THERE IS NO PROBLEM YOU CAN USE THIS CODE FOR SWIFT3 BUT REMEMBER YOU WOULD GET SOME WARNING FROM Alamorefire I THINK YOU NEED TO UPDATE YOUR POD FOR Alamorefire (IN CASE YOU ARE USING 2.3 POD FOR Alamorefire)

Comment: Im using the latest POD but still, Im getting an error in line :
return manager.request(urlRequest)  // API manager has no member 'request'

Comment: WHAT ERROR YOU GET

Comment: @dragoneye Please stop YELLING. Thank you.

Comment: rmaddy how can you check error if you don't know what the error you getting and secondly i am just asking for error log you take my answer in wrong way :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my manager in Swift 3.x with Alamofire 4.x and SwiftyJSON. I prefer class methods in place of Singletons.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class APIManager: NSObject {

class func apiGet(serviceName:String,parameters: [String:Any]?, completionHandler: @escaping (JSON?, NSError?) -> ()) {

    Alamofire.request(serviceName, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                let json = JSON(data)
                completionHandler(json,nil)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            completionHandler(nil,response.result.error as NSError?)
            break

        }
    }
}

class func apiPost(serviceName:String,parameters: [String:Any]?, completionHandler: @escaping (JSON?, NSError?) -> ()) {

    Alamofire.request(serviceName, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                let json = JSON(data)
                completionHandler(json,nil)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            completionHandler(nil,response.result.error as NSError?)
            break

        }
    }
}

}
```

Better to provide the name or url of service in controller itself with the `apiGet` and `apiPost` methods

How to use it.
 In your controller class or button event

First import `SwiftyJSON` in your controller

```
import SwiftyJSON
```

Then call your login service wherever you want

```
let params = [
        "userName":"abc",
        "password":"abc"
    ]

APIManager.apiPost(serviceName: "yourLoginURL", parameters: params) { (json:JSON?, error:NSError?) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        print(json!)
    }
```

Comment: sir It gives me an error saying cannot load the undeline module for 'Alamorefire'

Comment: Clean and build the project

Comment: Now it says use of undeclared type 'JSON'

Comment: What does this class have to do with Module Loading. Its just a simple helper code. Check your project settings with Alamofire

Comment: @danutha You have to `import SwiftyJSON` in your controller brother. These are basic things which you need to know.

Comment: I dont know where the issue is however much appreciate for trying

Comment: `import SwiftyJSON` in your viewcontroller

Comment: Would u mind taking few minutes of your time to explain the body of your code since im very much new to this

Comment: There are two generic methods for Get and Post Service with parameters which I have clubbed with Alamofire and closures and made them as helpers. 
Then we call those functions apiGet and apiPost within our controllers and they return the response or error from the closure itself in the controllers. They take the service URL and the parameters. If you don't wish to send parameters, keep them as empty `["":""]`.
Can I get an upvote for this :)

Comment: quick question.. in case if i wants to pass a int as a parameter how can i do it using your code

Comment: @danutha your parameter type in `[String:Any]`, it means the key is string and value is of Any type `let params = [
        "intValue":2,
        "password":"abc"
    ]`

Comment: Understood. So basically my success block is the place where you have  printed the json response, is that what you referring ?? So in the success of the servercall if i have to do any change (like assign a value to a label), underneath the line 'print(json!)' only I have to do right ?

Comment: There is actually a single block . If error is nil it means it's a success , you can do whatever you want there.if you are making UI changes, make them on main thread.

Comment: Sir Im Having troubles with catching the json response. Would you be kind enough to guid me on that

Comment: What is the problem you are having

Comment: Sir with your code above im getting a response with the type of JSON. In side that I have a structure as be bellow. Which i wants to assign it to an array.

{
   "media": [ 
    {
       "key" : "value"
       "Objectarray"[
          {
            "Object1":"somevalue"
          }
            "Object2":"somevalue"
         {
            "Object3":"somevalue"
         }
         ]
   
    }

    ]


I want to catch This "Objectarray" and assign it to a string array

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I want to create base_url var baseURL : String! {
        if var _baseURl = self.Base_Url{
                  return _baseURl
              }else{
                  return nil
              }
          } in APIManager class but got error. can you suggest me how to create.